# Parallax, as a homepage banner

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition, parallax

This is a very vague question, but I am not sure where to start, so if anyone could give me some idea, that you be great.

I want to have a Parallax effect on the homepage of my website, but I am unsure how to create this effect. The effect I want is crated here http://davegamache.com/chase-happiness/ and here http://themetrust.com/demos/hero/. They both use a similar principle to where as you scroll down the image and text move at different speed and fade out.

So basically my question is, does anyone know where I should start to create this or any download you can get which creates the effect.

Thank you for any help

Comment: You could start by studying the source of the pages you've linked.

Comment: Also, you could start at [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=parallax+scrolling+tutorial&fp=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks not that difficult, just look in their sourcecode at: http://themetrust.com/demos/hero/wp-content/themes/hero/js/theme_trust.js 
At the bottom there is a section named: Parallax